# Limit wheel event to just 1 wheel

Tags: javascript, mousewheel

I am creating a section animation on scroll like tesla's website (tesla.com) but when I wheel more than once, the animation bugs out

So what I want to do is limit the wheel event to 1 even if the user scrolls (let's say) 5 times, to prevent the visual bug, and maybe add a cooldown of 2 seconds when they can use wheel again after the animation stops landing into the new section

The following JS code is entirely on detecting the section's location and limiting the wheel/scrolling speed:

```
document.lastScrollPosition = 0;
document.lastCentered = 0;
document.onWayTo = null;
let timeout

document.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  const direction = window.pageYOffset - document.lastScrollPosition > 0 ? 'down' : 'up';
  const sections = [...document.querySelectorAll('section')];
  

  if (document.onWayTo === null) {
    const destIndex = direction === 'up' ? document.lastCentered - 1 : document.lastCentered + 1;
    if (destIndex >= 0 && destIndex < sections.length) {
      console.log({destIndex,direction});
      document.onWayTo = destIndex;
      window.scroll(0, sections[destIndex].offsetTop);
    }
  }


  sections.forEach((section,index) => {
    if (window.pageYOffset === section.offsetTop) {
      document.lastCentered = index;
      section.className = 'active'
      
      if (document.onWayTo === index) {
        document.onWayTo = null;
      }
    } else {
      section.className = '';
    }
    
    const content = document.querySelector("html");
    setTimeout(() => {   
    document.addEventListener("wheel", () => {
      

        event.preventDefault();
         // getting the scrolling speed.
         let deltaY = event.deltaY;
         
         // decreasing the scrolling speed by 50 times
         let sL = event.deltaY / 50;
         
         // scrolling the content of the div element
         content.scrollTop += sL;
        
         
      },{passive:false});
    
  })
  }, 1000);


  console.log(direction);
  document.lastScrollPosition = window.pageYOffset;
})
```